# How to add custom icon to Angular2 primeng Tree

Tags: javascript, angular, web-applications, primeng

I am creating tree using Primeng p-tree in my application and I need to add custom icons to tree nodes as shown in below JSON data. But tree node is not showing icons. If anyone has any idea please help me to resolve this issue.

```
{
            "label": "Pictures",
            "data": "Pictures Folder",
            "icon": "CustIcon.png",
            "children": [
                {"label": "Pic1", "icon": "icon1.png"},
                {"label": "Pic2", "icon": "icon2.png"},
                {"label": "Pic3", "icon": "icon3.png"}]
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem using a template:

```
<p-tree [value]="equipmentLibrary" selectionMode="single">
    <template let-node pTemplate type="default">
        <span><img class="tree-icon" src="{{node.icon}}" /></span>
    </template>
</p-tree>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Node is showing as [icon node.label] If I implement above mentioned approach. But I need icon to be separated from node as [icon][node.label] I fixed the issue by using a css class name in json data and the syle in css file as given below .abstract-icon {
 background: url("app/images/abstract-bo.png");
    height:16px;
    width:16px;
    float:initial;
}